# Mutation stage of genetic algorithm in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, genetic-algorithm, mutation, tomography-reconstruction

I'm optimizing an image reconstruction algorithm using genetic algorithm in Matlab.I did crossover on two population and generate two offsprings without using 'ga' toolkit in matlab. So presently I have two 1*n matrices with integer values ranging from 0-255(They are two images in row major order).for example

```
population_1 = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
population_2 = [10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100]
```

And I did single point ordered cross over and got offsprings as

```
Off_1 =  1     2     3     4     5    60    70    80    90   100
Off_2 =  10    20    30    40    50     6     7     8     9    10
```

Next I need to do mutation with probability rate of 0.02.I used 'gaoptimset' here and coded as follows.

```
 mutated_child = gaoptimset('MutationFcn', {@mutationuniform, .02})
```

and I printed the result.It gives a structure like this without any values.

```
mutated_child = 

    PopulationType: []
      PopInitRange: []
    PopulationSize: []
        EliteCount: []
 CrossoverFraction: []
    ParetoFraction: []
MigrationDirection: []
 MigrationInterval: []
 MigrationFraction: []
       Generations: []
         TimeLimit: []
      FitnessLimit: []
     StallGenLimit: []
    StallTimeLimit: []
            TolFun: []
            TolCon: []
 InitialPopulation: []
     InitialScores: []
    InitialPenalty: []
     PenaltyFactor: []
      PlotInterval: []
       CreationFcn: []
 FitnessScalingFcn: []
      SelectionFcn: []
      CrossoverFcn: []
       MutationFcn: {[@mutationuniform]  [0.0200]}
DistanceMeasureFcn: []
         HybridFcn: []
           Display: []
          PlotFcns: []
        OutputFcns: []
        Vectorized: []
       UseParallel: []
```

Can anyone please help me to perform mutation on crossovered childs(Off_1 and Off_2)?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about the GA toolbox.
But without it you could do something like:

```
% for offspring 1:

p_m = 0.02;
for i = 1:length(Off_1)
    if rand(1) < p_m
        Off_1(i) = randi([0,255],1);
    end
end
```

You should do the same thing with offspring no. 2